# How to get the length of the filtered resultant array in angular4?

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I have an array of objects which i am trying to filter with the search value

`component ts`

```
filterArray = [
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'ABC', 'type': 'IT'},
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'XYZ', 'type': 'Tech'},
    {'id': 3, 'name': 'LMN', 'type': 'IT'},
    {'id': 4, 'name': 'PQR', 'type': 'Software'},
    {'id': 5, 'name': 'JKL', 'type': 'hardware'},
    {'id': 5, 'name': 'EFG', 'type': 'hardware'}
  ];

 @ViewChildren('filterRef') filtedItems;
```

`custom pipe`

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    if (value && args) {
      const arr = value.filter((e: any) => e.type.toLowerCase() === args.toLowerCase());
      if (arr.length > 0) {
        return arr;
      } else {
        return [];
      }
    }
    return value;
  }

}
```

`HTML`

```
Search : <input type="text" name="search" [(ngModel)]="search">
<ul *ngFor="let item of filterArray | filter: search as result" #filterRef>
        <li>{{item.name}}</li>
    </ul>
    Filtered Length : {{filtedItems?.length}}
```

I am trying to get the length of the filtered resultant array am getting below error

[image]

can anyone help me to fix this?..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If filtering should be done with the pipe, the only possibility is to do that in a surrounding context:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="filterArray | filter: search as result">
    <ul *ngFor="let item of result" #filterRef>
        <li>{{item.name}}</li>
    </ul>
    <p>{{result?.length}}</p>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: I spent all day looking and this is by far the best solution. It feels hacky in that you aren't doing the filtering in the ngFor, but you are at least utilizing the ngIf as a check to make sure the filterArray is truthy and is much better than any other solution I've seen. How something that should be so simple is so difficult in Angular2+ is beyond me.